# How to automatically delete local profiles remotely via a Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, command-line, vbscript

I want to be able to create a script (say, in Python or whatever) or even a Batch file(??) that will let me run the following commands on multiple machines at once. These machines are on a network and each machine will have a unique workstation ID. In the example below, eg. computer1.

The following line is entered first into Windows Command Line.

> sc \computer1 start remoteregistry start= auto

After this, a confirmation appears to say that remote access has been enabled.
Then I have to type in the following, which runs an opensource program called DelProf.

```
DelProf2.exe -c:computer1
```

Following  this, in the same window, I type in 'Y' for yes and all profiles will automatically delete.

What I am trying to do is to run the above command on multiple machines at once, silently.  The workstationIDs are all on a spreadsheet (EXCEL file) and so the script would check the workstationID column and run the relevant command, without having to press 'Y' each time.

Comment: Can you dump the workstation names to a text file first? Could you test to see if this code works with DelProf2.exe first before we provide an automated solution. `echo Y |DelProf2.exe -c:computer1`

Comment: Powershell has remote execution capabilities. You might start at http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Comment: The delprof2 command has two switches you can use to answer the prompt. https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/#syntax-and-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can dump the computer names to a text file with one computer name on each line, this will read that text file and execute your two commands.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (computers.txt) DO (
    sc \\%%G start remoteregistry start= auto
    DelProf2.exe /u /c:%%G
)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Just needed a little tweaking  but it works a treat.